# Image upload in web page with correct orientation

Tags: javascript, python, ios, django, image

I have been going through a few SO questions and getting bits and pieces from it, but the solution is not fully apparent. What I have is a Django web server and in my model for posts I have an ImageField. I have then created my form and that renders fine.

I can use the input tag just fine, and it will upload to the server and location saves to the database. The problem comes when I take an image on an iOS device in portrait and view it on another platform e.g. Android, Desktop, the image will be rotated.

Now I have found out that when you take an image on iOS it will keep the resolution as landscape and put into the EXIF data the orientation of the image to make it portrait.

So finally my question is, what is the best approach to this issue. The options I have seen as are:

1. In the webpage where the upload occurs, transform the image and reset the orientation then upload to the server.
2. Upload as is, and in my view do the transform/reset before the save.
3. Again upload as is, and I render the image in the view detail post and fix it there.

I will also at some point also be creating some thumbnails and smaller instances of the image. Only thing my javascript skills are not the greatest!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For working with images python has some good packages.
`Pillow` :
You can use it from this link:

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/

or `Easy thumbnails for Django` (it is easy version and based on Pillow)

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/easy-thumbnails

Comment: Thanks, do you think that server side is the best option then?

Comment: When you upload image from IOS , in your service use pillow and rotate image and save it 
look at this:
http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#open-rotate-and-display-an-image-using-the-default-viewer